# How to call nested stored create table procedures in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Looking for advice on how to correct these two stored procedures so that one will trigger the other.

Stored procedure 2 is designed to simply create Table 2:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table_2()
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$

var create_table_2 = `
create or replace table DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE_2
(
COL_1 string,
COL_2 string,
COL_3 date
)
;
`
var create_table_2_cmd = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: create_table_2});
var result = sql_create_table_2.execute();
return 'Table 2 created';

$$;
```

And stored procedure 1, which should be run first, create table 1 and then run stored procedure 2:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table_1()
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$

var create_table_1 = `
create or replace table DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE_1
(
COL_1 string,
COL_2 string,
COL_3 date
)
;
`
var create_table_1_cmd = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: create_table_1 });
var result = create_table_1_cmd .execute();
return 'Table 1 created';

var call_next_function_cmd = `
call create_table_2();
;
`

var call_next_func = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: call_next_function_cmd});
var final = call_next_func.execute();

$$;
```

The SQL code within the create_table_1() procedure executes without issue but does not call the create_table_2() procedure. Is there an adjustment to be made that can trigger this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` has to be moved to the end of stored procedure, at current position it makes the second call [unreachable code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_table_1()
returns string not null
language javascript
as
$$

var create_table_1 = `
create or replace table DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLE_1
(
COL_1 string,
COL_2 string,
COL_3 date
)
;
`
var create_table_1_cmd = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: create_table_1 });
var result = create_table_1_cmd .execute();
//return 'Table 1 created';   -- << HERE

var call_next_function_cmd = `
call create_table_2();
;
`

var call_next_func = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: call_next_function_cmd});
var final = call_next_func.execute();

return '...';

$$;
```

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed the issue. 

Separately, I notice that the return statement to issue a string explaining that the table 2 has been created does not appear within the view result. Is there a way to have nested statements output return statements also?